# Laravel Homestead - configure php.ini file

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I'm on Windows10

So Laravel Homestead uses its own php installation, right. So what's the path to the php.ini file then? Can I access it via the file explorer or?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. So inside gitBash:

1. vagrant ssh
2. cd /etc/php/7.2/fpm
3. vi php.ini

Comment: When I make this change it doesn't seem to take effect. Is there something we need to do to reload or refresh the php.ini file after changes?

Answer (score 0):

[Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead) uses Vagrant to create a virtual machine of Ubuntu 18, Nginx, etc. The php configuration is within the virtual machine, not the Windows 10 file system. You'll wanna ssh into your virtual machine, php settings can be found in `/etc/php/7.*`

Answer (score 0):

It is a little off-topic and not really what you were asking for, but you can overwrite your PHP files via `ini_set`. Just think of it, in the end, your live (clients) server might require a php.ini override. And you cannot change the server configuration file.